# Does code allow cutting a hole in the back of an indoor breaker box?

Tags: electrical-panel, walls, circuit-breaker, hole, cutting

We have an inside breaker box and want to install a dedicated line to an exterior outlet. In order to do that we are thinking to cut a hole in the back of the breaker box and another in the outside wall of the house to push the cable that way and after that using conduit up to the outlet. Are there any restrictions for that in Texas?

Comment: Where in the back of the breaker box are you wanting to cut this hole, what size of hole do you need to cut/what size cable are you running to this outlet, and what make/model is your breaker box? Photos of said breaker box would be very helpful in this endeavor as well...

Comment: Would you void the U.L. Rating?

Comment: No punching holes in a service panel will not void the UL listing. Some panels come with no knock outs pre punched, others have a bunch of holes all over around the sides & back, these usually have multiple sizes inside or outside like 1/2. -3/4 , or 3/4-1 and or TKO that may ho from 1/2” up to 1-1/2” if using conduit for a ground we don’t like tko’s or most do not like them. A bare panel that we punch provides a superior ground. Service panels are expected to be modified in either case and the gutter space or wire way area is commonly modified to add conduit / wireways.

Answer (score 2):

While it may be technically OK (I am not a code expert), unless it must be directly behind the panel, far better would be to connect to one of the sides or top or bottom, then turn 90 degrees to go through the wall. You might need an extra little piece of conduit or two, but if there is ever a need to replace the entire panel, it will be much easier not having to worry about lining up a hole in the new panel.

Comment: It is ok but the hole can not interfere with the breakers or framework. The “gutter” area above below right or left of the breakers are all common for electricians. If adding in an existing panel it’s best to stay away from the feeder, a hole saw will take off the insulation really quick and even a small service can produce a massive arc flash (not good).

Comment: @EdBeal Obviously the hole has to be away from the breakers, feeder, etc. Any mistake there could be *interesting*. My extra concern is that if a panel is replaced - e.g., there are plenty of posts about replacing a smaller panel with a larger one - then the hole could be in a bad place for the new panel or, even if it is still "OK", require drilling a hole in the new panel which would have to be done just right to keep things lined up. Go around the side and it is much simpler.

Comment: The main difference in old and new is the gutter space was increased. The same sized breakers. Other than the number of breakers being increased so there can be more the width and a longer line of breakers so if the panel can not be moved up the old circuits get moved to the sides.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can punch a hole through the back. I usually try to use the space below the breakers (in fact if you look you may have pre punched knockouts there already.

If you don’t have pre punched holes you can use an appropriately sized hole saw and punch a hole,  using locknuts to secure the conduit to both the box and panel.

I try to place my box next to a stud so I can anchor the box after putting the conduit and lock nuts in when it is flush mounted.

If surface mounted it is actually easier with a bell box and the nipple screwed into the box mark the inside put the locknut inside the mark and insert it back in the panel and lock nut it in place. At this point if the box is against the siding put the 2 anchor screws in the ears. Some electricians will drill the back of the box and put screws in (if there is a boss or place made for this it is ok)

Ok that is the rigid conduit way you can do the same with pvc if it is a 6” stud wall and surface mount, much easier than rigid pipe but the 2 connectors for pvc will not fit in a 4” stud wall behind the panel. I drill the hole the same then put the threaded coupling in the back of the box and install the lock nut inside using the piece of unglued conduit to hold it in place measure and cut the conduit, verify it will fit then glue the conduit and press the box tight to the siding.

I usually put plastic bushings on the end of the nipple, it’s not required on smaller sizes (12 & 14 awg) but inspectors love them.

I would use a weather rated GFCI receptacle on a 20 amp for outside circuits but there is not a size requirement 15 amp bkr with 14 awg wire will work or 20 amp bkr with 12 awg wire.

Both sizes will fit in 1/2” conduit the box requires a heavy duty / in use cover I suggest the metal ones they are a few dollars more but they last every plastic one I have seen as most everyone has been broken.

Not hard and code legal I do normally use some Silicone around the hole in the siding to seal from water and small bugs.